# Avoiding rerenders in React Child when using a callback to Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to have a Parent component handle a trigger from a Child component without rerendering the Child component whenever the Parent state changes. The handle on the Parent uses values in the Parent state but doesn't set them.

```js
const OuterComponent = () => {
  // State changes should not rerender Child
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  const handle = () => {
    //
  }

  return (
    <Parent>
      <ComponentsSettingStateInParent />
      <Child onTrigger={handle} />
    </Parent>
  )
}
```

I tried to compose the affair like this in order to avoid rerenders, but of course it then becomes impossible to pass the handle:

```js
const OuterComponent = () => {

  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child onTrigger={handle} />
    </Parent>
  )
}

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  // State changes should not rerender Child
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  const handle = () => {
    //
  }

  // I'd like to pass the handle here to Child
  return
  (
    <div>
      <ComponentsSettingStateInParent />
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't want to handle the trigger in `OuterComponent`, because I'll then have to keep all state from `Parent` in `OuterComponent` which will cause even more unnecessary renders.

I thought about using `cloneElement` and pass the handle as a prop to `children` inside the `Parent` render, but I've never used it before and I'm not sure it's the best solution (documentation suggests avoiding it, too).

How can this be achieved otherwise?

Comment: You can wrap your function with a `useCallback` and use `React.memo` for you child component

Comment: I can't use `memo` for the Child component, because its own state updates too frequently for it to have any practical use. I tried, though, but even with `memo` any updates to the `Parent` state causes `Child` to rerender.

Comment: In addition to the `useCallback`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with both.

Comment: The problem is that the `handle` in `Parent` needs access to `state` in `Parent`. That state is modified by `ComponentsSettingStateInParent`, so wrapping the handler with `useCallback` doesn't help (its dependencies change whenever `ComponentsSettingStateInParent` modifies the state). But `Child` is oblivious to all this. It only needs to trigger the `handle` in `Parent`. Whatever I try, I can't compose this without causing unnecessary rerenders in `Child`.